# Is there a (winter-bash) hat that can depict the IPS.SE?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

From [A Moose, Some Silly Putty... And A Desperate Plea For Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help), I *"collected"* some hats made by members of this community, just for the record.
I may not have found all of them, so feel free to add the ones I missed by editing this post...

1. [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304644/359002)
2. [Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304618/359002)
3. [HDE 226868](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304568/359002)
4. [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304578/359002) and [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304640/162102)
5. [AJ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304737/359002)
6. [Myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304796/359002)
7. [Rory Alsop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304584)

Now, the point. Because I'm looking for ideas in order to craft another hat for us, I'd like your help. I understand that this is completely off-topic, and opinion-based, so I hope that, once in a while, we can *chill out* and let this be on meta? ;)

**What would be an appropriate hat, representative of the IPS community?**

Of course, any idea is welcome as long as it's something that sticks to the rules of the original topic and our be-nice policy. And anyone wishing to give a hand to implement the project is welcome.

If you think this is a bad idea, well... DV and comment, thanks :)

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek or serious (really representative)?

Comment: @AnneDaunted : community will tell, I'm open ! We can make it either way (maybe one of each?)

Comment: Off the top of my hat (sorry, I know I'm silly), if it were to be tongue-in-cheek maybe something inspired by prejudices against IPS: Soft and "opinion-based". Something that depicts those - maybe abstract art about whose meaning you can argue endlessly.

Comment: @AnneDaunted, that would be stinky cheese and wine :P The cheese is soft, and whether or not a wine tastes good is very opinion based :P I'm not putting a stinky cheese on my head though!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell : any Packers' fan couldn't [disagree more](https://imgur.com/a/UjS4C)... Maybe you can seek for an IPS solution to avoid this hat? :))

Comment: @OldPadawan That's clearly a Gouda cheese, not a stinky one! :-P I was thinking along the lines of this: https://www.bavorsko.eu/data/mediadb/cms_pictures/%7B086d67a0-3e71-6613-4dad-8f87f94fa9e1%7D.jpg Anyways, I think the cheese is a bad idea, there's already a cheese hat ;-) That's why I didn't make it an answer ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Maybe a hat for 2 people?

A bit like [these christmas sweaters](https://www.google.nl/search?q=2+person+christmas+sweater&rlz=1C1MSIM_enNL740NL740&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVw5bk5ZbYAhWRmbQKHdqwDIUQsAQILA&biw=1920&bih=974).

Because Interpersonal skills are all about 'interacting well with other people'.

And, it can even be used to teach people how to get along:

[image]

Comment: Excellent one too!

Comment: For a goal, we might use 'make a community wiki post' or something? :P

Comment: Who are these poor victims in this picture?

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel random google people ;-) Don't worry, no kids were harmed during the creation of this idea :P

Comment: That's one hell of a "hat".

Comment: Easiest real-life version I can come up with is tying two santa hats together, either really tying or using duct-tape/string. If any one has a better idea, I'm curious!

Comment: What about [this one](https://imgur.com/a/kKain), from @Rory-Alsop + @ Tinkeringbell 's suggestions? you get the *twin hat* + the hug :)

Comment: @OldPadawan Looks good ;-) Who's going to post it? ;)

Answer (score 6):

How about something a bit like [e-sushi's reindeer hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304606/154443), but have the hands actually shaking hands.

[image]

You'd only need to angle them in a bit, and maybe change the face to be two people facing each other and smiling :-)

Comment: Love that idea :)

Comment: of course a hug could be better :-)

Comment: Or a handshake!

Comment: hahahaha - very good @Vylix. I like that.

Comment: @ Rory: working around your ideas, I ended up with [this model](https://imgur.com/a/tVJTO). Still thinking of @Tinkeringbell 's idea too...

Comment: That's very nice - and expands out from just a 1-to-1 to a group

Comment: @OldPadawan that one looks good! :-) I think it deserves it's own 'answer' instead of being buried in comments!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell + Rory: thanks, appreciate. Now we need a **real** *art and craft big-shot* to do it properly and have it look nice if community wants to keep this idea too... y'know what I mean? ;)

Comment: Had you thought of asking someone crafty, like, I dunno, @Catija? ;-P

Comment: hm... not only her, though... there's also someone from... can't remember right now, but it's a country well known for its cheese, tulips, and... possibly *arts-and-crafts-women*? ^^

Answer (score 6):

Well, the following have been done pretty quickly, hopefully expanding the ideas of @Rory-Alsop + @Tinkeringbell into some *paper work*, and it could *definately* be much more nicely crafted by some skilled users around here... ;-D <sup>(1)</sup>

Here are two hats:

**#1 : Hand shaking shapes a heart, and its support is made by a Human Solidarity Chain**

[image: Hand shaking shapes a heart, and its support is made by a Human Solidarity Chain]

---

**#2 : A twin-hat with 2 non-gendered persons hugging**

[image: A twin-hat with 2 non-gendered persons hugging]

---

<strike>Still struggling with a *tongue-in-cheek* solution, as proposed by @Anne-Daunted...</strike> NOT anymore! Well, kind of...

**Here's the *twisted-by-the-fool* "hat"** (actually, more like a Stetson hat band)

Why is it twisted? Because of the "*infinity sign*" that alludes to IPS reputation being *one-weird-of-a-kind* place, with endless arguing, lack of harshness, and no clear guiding line?... and so on?...

The twisted band is made (both sides) of quotes found on IPS.

[image]
[image]

---

<sup>(1) look at my eyes staring at **both** of you, nice and skilled young ladies... ^^</sup>

Comment: I'm going to pass on posting another hat. My entry is doing just fine, so I'm going to let someone else nick the idea and get a box of goodies too :D

Comment: I thought my Ha(t)mmer wasn't that bad, but it took long before I get to post it, and it's been buried on page #3 :/ No way I get a reward over there (*shrug*)

Comment: Everything with a positive score is getting a reward. And you really must advertise your post in a chatroom, that helps! :P

Comment: No big deal, and no advertisement, it's just for fun :)

Comment: Pretty sure there's only one side.